# How to interpret effect significance and effect size of Categories in Logistic Regression?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, categorical-data, interpretation, logit

This is a follow up to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33240/interpretation-of-reference-category-in-logistic-regression) question on this site.

Let's say I'm doing a Logistic Regression with 2 Independent Variables (IVs). One IV is ordinal and named `AGE`, and the other is categorical and named `SERVICE` with 3 categories: `A`, `B` and `C`.

Let's say I get the following result:

**Scenario 1:**

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)  
                   Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
AGEP                1 1154.18  < 2.2e-16 ***
as.factor(SERVICE)  4  450.12  < 2.2e-16 ***

Coefficients:
                         Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                1.1     5.974e-02  -1.748 0458 *** 
AGE                        1.2     1.038e-03 -33.973  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(SERVICE)B        1.3     3.572e-02   5.175 2.27e-07 ***
as.factor(SERVICE)C        1.4     3.448e-02  -1.515 0.129877    

(note: *** indicates significant p-value at some desired level)
```

Here's how I think one would interpret the results of the `SERVICE` variable:

- Being in the category `A` is a significant predictor of the outcome, with an effect size of `1.1` on the log of the odds ratio.
- Being in the category `B` is a significant predictor of the outcome, and is significantly different than being in category `A`, with an effect size of `1.3` on the log of the odds ratio.
- Being in the category `C` is not significantly different than being in category `A` (in its effect on the outcome).

**Question 1: Is the above interpretation correct (for the `SERVICE` variable)?**

---

**Scenario 2:**

Let's say I get the following result:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)  
                   Df   Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
AGEP                1 1154.18  < 2.2e-16 ***
as.factor(SERVICE)  4  450.12  < 2.2e-16 ***

Coefficients:
                         Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                1.1     5.974e-02  -1.748 0.20458  
AGE                        1.2     1.038e-03 -33.973  < 2e-16 ***
as.factor(SERVICE)B        1.3     3.572e-02   5.175 2.27e-07 ***
as.factor(SERVICE)C        1.4     3.448e-02  -1.515 0.129877
```

**Notice that `Intercept` is no longer significant.**

Here's how I think one would interpret the results of the `SERVICE` variable:

- Being in the category `A` is not a significant predictor of the outcome.
- Being in the category `B` is a significant predictor of the outcome, with an effect size of `1.3` on the log of the odds ratio.
- Being in the category `C` is not a significant predictor of the outcome.

**Question 2: Is the above interpretation correct (for the `SERVICE` variable)?**

Comment: I don't think you should say "Being in the category A is not a significant predictor of the outcome."  It's A vs B (or C) changes the probability of the outcome.

Comment: @JeremyMiles How about 'B' vs. 'C' in Scenario 2? What would the interpretation be for that? That there's no significant difference?

Comment: This all looks terminally weird to me. how do the significance levels change when the p-values are the same? and why are the z not the result of the obvious divisions?

Comment: You don't know about the significance of the difference between B and C, without running the model again with a different reference category. Read up on dummy variables.

Comment: (Why does service have 8 df?)

Comment: @mdewey Good catch. It was a contrived example. I changed the p-value to be something appropriate to non-significance.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Good catch. The result set was copy pasted from a real result and then truncated and modified to make it shorter and more readable for StackOverflow. I've now changed the DF to be correct.